# R access to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, r

I'm having to update my access to SQL Server from R on windows. The only option I see right now is [`odbc`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/odbc/index.html). Unfortunately, the ODBC standard and this driver (using `nanodbc`) in particular has some problems that are difficult to ignore:

- Microsoft "updated" their ODBC driver years ago to require any "large-ish" columns must be requested last (fails with `Invalid Descriptor Index`; an [issue for `nanodbc`](https://github.com/nanodbc/nanodbc/issues/149) was closed, not fixed), requiring me to know a lot more about the structure of the table than I need to know in other DBMSs
- `datetimeoffset` is unsupported (https://github.com/r-dbi/odbc/issues/207), though this can be worked around by manually parsing the string; unfortunately, it seems to be losing millisecond precision and adds the TZ as (for example) `Pacific Standard Time`, and not something like more "standard" like `-07:00`, `-0700`, or `+07` (or even `PDT` or `America/Los_Angeles`, though I prefer the first two)
- an older version of ODBC that is not encumbered with the first bullet (column order "bug") breaks some string-equality tests, and comparison against `nvarchar(max)` columns fails with `The data types ntext and varchar are incompatible in the equal to operator` (I opened an [issue at `odbc`](https://github.com/r-dbi/odbc/issues/216), pending); workarounds require changing every query that does this

The non-ODBC driver [`RSQLServer`](http://github.com/imanuelcostigan/RSQLServer) has been deprecated in lieu of the "newer" `odbc` driver. [One suggestion](https://github.com/r-dbi/odbc/issues/112#issuecomment-414316114) was to look at the RStudio professional database odbc drivers, but those are unixy-only.

So are there DBI-friendly methods for accessing a SQL Server? Basic requirements:

- Windows 10
- R-3.4 or newer
- [`DBI`](http://github.com/r-dbi/DBI)-compatible (or similar-enough)
- supports variable binding (via string-interpolation)
- preferably not `rJava`-based (I could always risk using `RSQLServer`, even if unmaintained)
- linux compatbility is desired but not strictly required

(For the record: I do not control the server, but must access it; I cannot affect the schema, so column-order is fixed; I believe that [R Services for SQL Server](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/advanced-analytics/r/sql-server-r-services?view=sql-server-2017) will not suffice, I still need simultaneous access to files/resources not available to the server.)

Comment: Perhaps some glue language in between that could grab the SQL data, write to a file that your R set up can then read or dump to a temp local machine db table or something that is easier to work with on the R end of things?  Tempted to recommend asking on stackoverflow ...

Comment: I'm active on SO, and I thought the solution was too close to SO's off-topic *"recommend or find a book, tool, software library"*. The "glue" solution is certainly possible, in which case I'd likely use extensive and repetitive calls to `bcp`, `isql`, and/or `sqlcmd`, but ... dang, that will perform horribly, esp considering I'm running dozens/hundreds of queries per hour. It makes binding a little harder, lots of test-code to guard shell-escaped quotes and/or sql-injection-like errors.

Comment: Yeah, that's why I said "tempted" :) I only played with R a little bit when I took my college stats class, and then out of curiosity so I don't know enough about R and complex work flow.. i'm sure there has to be a decent way of doing the odbc thing and having that work as needed for data pulls and process it in R... but I also remember odbc being a royal pita when I used it in school...

Comment: +1 on the ODBC/pita, it is (and usually *has*) proving troublesome. I actually considered using R's [`reticulate`](https://rstudio.github.io/reticulate/) to connect via python's `pymssql` native library, but ... that's moving in the same direction as `rJava`.